# How to change all caps text to normal case with the first word capitalized in sentences in PhraseExpress?

Tags: windows, macros, clipboard, phraseexpress

How do I get all caps to normal text? These are the codes that I've tried & how they've turned out. Some work & some don't. Also, I'm somewhat new to PhraseExpress so this is all a whole new language to me.

Test Text -  test test TEsT Test Test TESTING TEST tESt

```
{#clipboard -cut}{#autocase {#insertclipboard}}
Test test TEsT Test Test TESTING TEST tESt
```

```
{#clipboard -cut}{#uppercase {#insertclipboard}}
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TESTING TEST TEST
```

```
{#clipboard -cut}{#autocase {#insertclipboard}}
Test test TEsT Test Test TESTING TEST tESt
```

```
{#clipboard -cut}{#uppercasefirst {#insertclipboard}}
Test test TEsT Test Test TESTING TEST tESt
```

```
{#clipboard -cut}{#lowercase {#insertclipboard}}
test test test test test testing test test
```

```
{#clipboard -cut}{#uppercaseword {#insertclipboard}}
Test Test TEsT Test Test TESTING TEST TESt
```